# Azure Free Trial account VM size is greyed

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I have a free trial for azure . I am trying to create an initial windows machine with B1S size ( Free service ) . All the sizes are greyed out . I am in region US ( EAST ) . What can be the problem . I signed out and signed back in, still see the issue. I am going through the following option Home>Free Services > Create a Virtual machine . So what can be the problem

Comment: Contact Microsoft Support.

Answer (score 2):

If you read here you'll find out why: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/our-commitment-to-customers-and-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/

In 6th paragraph it says: We will also consider adjusting free offers, as necessary, to ensure support of existing customers.